# Chai is breaking jest (expect.assertions(1)) in my tests

Tags: jestjs, chai

I think chai is breaking my jest tests of my express.js application.
I'm getting the following error:

> TypeError: expect.assertions is not a function

I need chai in my project to run my cucumber tests, but I don't need it for my jest unit/integration tests.

I haven't required chai in the jest tests or anything.

Can I have separate dependencies for unit tests and cucumber tests? Obviously both are currently in the `devDependencies` section of my package.json file.

Or can I un-require chai, somehow?

Thanks very much for any and all assistance anyone can offer.

Doug.

Comment: Okay, I've stripped chai and am using supertest and superagent, instead.

However, now the `expect` function isn't available anywhere. Does anyone know how to import it from jest?

Comment: Hey Doug, expect should be available globally for any jest tests. This article may be helpful for your issue http://www.andrewsouthpaw.com/2017/05/12/jest-chai-and-expect-assertions/. If not, can you push a repo?

Comment: Thanks Rick -- my acceptance tests aren't written in jest, but cucumber.js. Maybe the answer is that I shouldn't be bucking trends with testing and just stick to jest. Incidentally, the `assert` methods are all working in my cucumber tests with supertest and superagent. So things are working if not as aesthetically pleasing!